# Multi Spark Context job

Tags: apache-spark

**Scenerio 1 :**
If we have multiple spark context in a application and one of the job fails then what will happen to the other job and the other spark context will it execute or fail?

**Scenario 2:**
And if both are running will it give same or different result set?

Can someone explain these scenarios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://data-flair.training/blogs/fault-tolerance-in-apache-spark/

Comment: @JAdel Thanks for sharing but will it be same if we have multiple spark context jobs aswell? will the first spark context continue to execute even if the second one fails?